# javascript regex to exclude a pattern only if another pattern does not match

Tags: javascript, regex

A regex is needed in order to exclude sentences with `wag[.|on]` or `ut[i|e]` but only if NO `sed[.|an]` is present and allow all other sentences. any suggestions?
ie. exclude matches that are only wagon or only ute.

I tried `/[^wag[on|.]]/ig.test(sentence)` but this way will not allow exclusion. I need to select the "yes" sentences only as below.

Given the following sentences:
the sedan is fast     <-- yes
other sed. is fast too  <-- yes
the wagon is slow  <-- no
other wag. is also slow  <-- no
the ute is slow  <-- no
other uti is also slow  <-- no
the wag. and wagon slower then sed. or sedan   <-- yes
the uti or ute is slower then sed. or sedan  <-- yes
both wag. wagon and uti and ute are slow  <-- no
nothing is fast or slow  <-- yes

Comment: have you considered to use two regex for this? I don't think you can make it one.

Comment: could you give some solution as to how you could do it with 2 regex. thx

Comment: do you mean `wag[.|on]` or `wag(on)?` or `wag(.|on)`? they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this does the trick

```
function isMatch(input) {
   var regno = /(wag[.|on]|ut[i|e])/gi;
   var regyes = /sed[.|an]/gi;
   return !regno.test(input) || regyes.test(input);
}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:.*sed[.|an].*|(?:(?!wag[.|on]|ut[i|e]).)*)$/
```

you can use `(?!)` to match a string who do not match some pattern.